# Getting context for Glide, within a fragment, results in error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In this method, I'm attempting to use a framework to retrieve an image from a URL and store it as a bitmap. However, if I attempt to use it, I get a nullpointer exception.

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.Activity.isDestroyed()' on a null object reference"

I'm assuming it's something to do with using getActivity() for the context in Glide.with(). This method (below) is within a fragment.

```
private void generateMarker(final GeoLocation location, final GoogleMap globalMap, String userName, String key){
    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();

final String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + key + "/picture?type=large";

marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)).title(userName);

//downloadImage.execute(url);
//downloadImage.setOnDownloadImageListener(this);

Bitmap mBmap = null;
try {
    mBmap = Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(100, 100)
            .get();
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}

//Doing something with mBmap that results in null
```

}

**My Log cat**

```
 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
                                                                at maps.w.d.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                at maps.ad.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                at maps.ad.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                at maps.ad.S.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                at ua.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:167)
                                                                at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.test.project.PostFragment.generateMarker(PostFragment.java:255)
                                                                at com.test.project.PostFragment.access$300(PostFragment.java:51)
                                                                at com.test.project.PostFragment$3.onDataChange(PostFragment.java:224)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: what do you mean by .into(-1,-1) ? isnt there you put your imageview ?

Comment: @ArifNoumanKhan yes, sorry that was a small mistake on my part, it should be 100, 100. but that's not the reason why i'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `mBmap`, but `get()` is meant to be used on a background thread, therefore `mBmap` is still `null`. The method `into(int width, int height)` is also deprecated. The [correct way](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets) to load into a `Bitmap` would be the following:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
    .load(url)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100, 100) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
            // Do something with bitmap here
        }
    };
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But I'm still getting "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.Activity.isDestroyed()' on a null object reference"

Comment: @SaltySea That would mean that your `Activity` is `null`, how did that happen? What line is that error getting called on?

Comment: The line is @ "Glide.with(getActivity())", I'm not sure why. :/

Comment: @SaltySea Are you somehow calling `getActivity()` before [`onAttach()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) (or after `onDetach()`)? When are you calling `Glide.with()` in your `Fragment`?

Comment: I figured out my problem. I've been calling the method where I have Glide.with() after the fragment is destroyed so that's probably why I'm getting the context as null. I think if I just clean up my code and put my methods in the right classes then it should work. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

sorry if im late but i have somthing that helped me in This case ..so it meight be silly and i don't know why it worked so lets go..
 i delcared a context

```
context=getactivity().getapplicationContext();
```

and in Glide methode

```
 Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
            .load(Url).asBitmap().fitCenter()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                  //your stuff here


                }
            });
```